# Derefrencing of 'binding' produces NullPointer Exception

Tags: android, android-databinding

Declare an array of Croller(https://android-arsenal.com/details/1/5079) -

```
Croller[] croller = new Croller[]{binding.crollerThirtyOnetwentyHertz,binding.crollerOnetwentyFoursixtyHertz,binding.crollerFoursixtyOnekiloHertz,
                        binding.crollerOnekiloSevenkiloHertz,binding.crollerSevenkiloHertz};
```

Use it: On setting the label of Croller using data binding shows Null Pointer Exception

```
for (int i = 0; i < numBands; i++)
{
    freqRange = eq.getBandFreqRange((short)i);
    croller[i].setLabel ("Anything Printed Here"));
}
```

Comment: That means the ith indec of the array must be null (where i is wherever it failed).  There's nothing that stops an array element from being null.

Comment: I had initialized an array so why it is null @GabeSechan

Comment: You can initialize an array element to null. Did you check that all those binding.xxx values were non null?